# Konva.js is very laggy on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, konvajs

I want to start using `Konva.js` library. It looks really great in my browser (chrome) on my PC and has awesome functionality. I created code to  make some really easy animations (move and rotate). But when I tried to run my webpage on a mobile device or even in Safari browser, it started to be really laggy. Moreover, when I set four objects(Images) into a movement, the browser crashed.

I did some tests and realized that even draggable objects are laggy on mobile devices. (When I tried to move them, they had really slow and jerky movement).

Is there some way to optimize it. (I have tried the recommended `batchDraw()` function, but it didn't help)? How can I make the movement fluent? If this is not currently possible, will there be some optimization possibilities in the future?

Here is my code... but obviously you have to run it on a mobile phone to see the effect. To activate the effect click(touch) on images.

http://bannerteam.tode.cz/konvaAnim/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Konva animace</title>
    <style>
        body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #F0F0F0;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konvajs/konva/2.0.3/konva.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
<script>
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    var lengthOfAnim = 60;
    var pos = [{x: 50, y: 50, p: 'A'}, {x: 250, y: 50, p: 'B'}, {x: 450, y: 50, p: 'C'},
                {x: 50, y: 250, p: 'D'}, {x: 250, y: 250, p: 'E'}, {x: 450, y: 250, p: 'F'},
                {x: 50, y: 450, p: 'G'}, {x: 250, y: 450, p: 'I'}, {x: 450, y: 450, p: 'J'},
                {x: 50, y: 650, p: 'K'}, {x: 250, y: 650, p: 'F'}];

    var stage = new Konva.Stage({
      container: 'container',
      width: width,
      height: height
    });

    var imageObj = [];
    var img = new Image();

    var doAnimations = function(i){
        switch(i){
            case 0:
                imageObj[i].img.opacity(1 - imageObj[i].time/lengthOfAnim);
                break;
            case 1:
                if(imageObj[i].time === lengthOfAnim -1)
                    imageObj[i].img.y(imageObj[i].img.y() + (lengthOfAnim-1)*2);
                else
                    imageObj[i].img.y(imageObj[i].img.y() - 2);
                break;
            case 2:
                imageObj[i].img.opacity(1 - imageObj[i].time/lengthOfAnim);
                if(imageObj[i].time === lengthOfAnim -1)
                    imageObj[i].img.y(imageObj[i].img.y() + (lengthOfAnim-1)*2);
                else
                    imageObj[i].img.y(imageObj[i].img.y() - 2);
                break;
            case 3:
                var parent = imageObj[i].img.getParent();
                parent.clipFunc(function(ctx) {
                    ctx.rect(imageObj[i].img.x() - 75, imageObj[i].img.y() - 75, 75*(1 - imageObj[i].time/lengthOfAnim), 150);
                    ctx.rect(imageObj[i].img.x() + 75 - 75*(1 - imageObj[i].time/lengthOfAnim) , imageObj[i].img.y() - 75, 75*(1 - imageObj[i].time/lengthOfAnim), 150);
                });
                break;
            case 4:
                var parent = imageObj[i].img.getParent();
                parent.clipHeight(150*(1 - imageObj[i].time/lengthOfAnim));
                break;
            case 5:
                imageObj[i].img.opacity(1 - imageObj[i].time/lengthOfAnim);
                imageObj[i].img.rotation(90*(imageObj[i].time/lengthOfAnim));
                break;
            case 6:
                imageObj[i].img.opacity(1 - imageObj[i].time/lengthOfAnim);
                var pom = (1 - imageObj[i].time/lengthOfAnim);
                imageObj[i].img.scale({x: pom, y: pom});
                break;
            case 7:
                if(imageObj[i].time === lengthOfAnim -1)
                    imageObj[i].img.x(imageObj[i].img.x() - (lengthOfAnim-1)*2);
                else
                    imageObj[i].img.x(imageObj[i].img.x() + 2);
                imageObj[i].img.move({x: 0, y: 10*(Math.sin(6*Math.PI*(imageObj[i].time/lengthOfAnim)))});
                break;
            case 8:
                imageObj[i].img.rotation(20*Math.sin(6*Math.PI*(imageObj[i].time/lengthOfAnim)));
                break;
            case 9:
                imageObj[i].img.opacity(0.5 + Math.abs((imageObj[i].time/lengthOfAnim-0.5)));
                break;
            case 10:
                imageObj[i].img.draggable(true);
                break;
        }

    }

    img.onload = function() {
        for(let i = 0; i < pos.length; i++){
            var layer = new Konva.Layer();

            var yoda = new Konva.Image({
                x: pos[i].x + 75,
                y: pos[i].y + 75,
                image: img,
                width: 150,
                height: 150,
                offset: {
                    x: 75,
                    y: 75
                }
                });

            imageObj.push({img: yoda, layer: layer, time: 0});

            var charac = new Konva.Text({
                x: pos[i].x + 50,
                y: pos[i].y + 160,
                text: pos[i].p,
                fontSize: 30,
                fontFamily: 'Calibri',
                fill: 'black'
            });

            if(i === 3){
                var group = new Konva.Group({clipFunc:function(ctx) {
                        ctx.rect(pos[i].x, pos[i].y, 150, 150)
                    },});
                group.add(yoda);
                layer.add(group);
            }else if(i === 4){
                var group = new Konva.Group({clip: {
                    x : pos[i].x,
                    y : pos[i].y,
                    width : 150,
                    height : 150
                    },});
                group.add(yoda);
                layer.add(group);
            }else
                layer.add(yoda);
            layer.add(charac);

            stage.add(layer);

            yoda.on('click tap', function() {
                if(imageObj[i].time === 0)
                    imageObj[i].time = lengthOfAnim;
            });
        }
        setInterval(function(){
            for(var i = 0; i < pos.length; i++){
                if(imageObj[i].time > 0){
                    imageObj[i].time--;
                    doAnimations(i);
                    imageObj[i].layer.draw();
                }
            }
        }, 40);
    }

    img.src = './castle.png';

</script>
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your site has an error, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'time' of undefined`

Comment: @Derek yes, i know, it is just because setinterval runs sooner, than images are created, but it is not the problem. i can fix it, but thanks for comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to improve the performance.

You can read a lot of tips here: https://konvajs.github.io/docs/performance/All_Performance_Tips.html

Your stage looks simple, so performance should be very good on mobile.

Some tips:

1. Do not use `setInterval`. Use `requestAnimationFrame`. The animation will be much smoother
2. use `layer.batchDraw()`
3. If possible try to move animated objects into another layer, so you don't need to redraw ALL nodes

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using requestAnimationFrame is new information for me, thanks. I have tried layer.batchDraw(). And I think I used all useful tips form the site. I hope i have every image in separate layer. Unfortunately it didnt help. I'm not sure, should I edit question and update my code?

Comment: @Garenskilled you may share updated code. Also you can try to use `Konva.Tween` object or `node.to()` method

Comment: You are right, I put all nodes into one layer and its ok... Thank you.